# Using autosuggest on dependency jars that are downloaded by Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-13

I'm pretty new to Gradle and IntelliJ and I'm trying to understand how it works [cos that's what my project uses]. I created a simple java project in Intellij IDEA with a HelloWorld class and manually added the gradle.build file along with the necessary dependencies as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'main.java.test.HelloWorld'

dependencies {
    compile  'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gradle-test'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.java.test.HelloWorld'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2'
}
```

While I specified the joda-time dependency, my IntelliJ project is unaware of this library and therefore I can't use of any of the autosuggest features of IntelliJ for the joda-time library. 
Could someone give me information on how I can get IntelliJ to automatically start recognizing the downloaded jars and allow me to use the auto-suggest features?
In other words,

- where are the dependency jars downloaded ?
- How can I have these jars    to automatically be included in the
  class path of the project ? [Is    it ok to do so ? If not, what
  would be your recommendation ?]

Thanks !

Comment: This will happen automatically if you either import the Gradle build into IntelliJ (*Import Project*) or run `gradle idea` and open the generated IntelliJ project.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That did solve my problem of being able to use IntelliJ's autosuggestion features. I'm leaving the question open for now to get an answer on the remaining question asked.

Comment: A SO post should have exactly one question. Check the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for an answer to the other question.

Comment: I'm new here and I don't mean to offend at all. But having another SO post with 90% of the same content [for context] seems so very unnecessary especially since the question is related. Also, I had taken a look at the Gradle-User-Guide (which is huge) and specially Chapter-8 related to Dependency Management but either I overlooked something or I looked in the wrong place and couldn't find the information. Hence asked the question.

Comment: SO is Q&A site, not a forum. The question "where are the dependency jars downloaded" doesn't need the same context as your other question, and nobody will find it if it's mixed into another question titled "Using autosuggest on dependency jars that are downloaded by Gradle".

Comment: Allright, I wasn't sure if my build.gradle file is necessary to understand where the jars are downloaded. Btw, this wasn't a discussion, they were just two question clubbed into one post. Still qualifies for Q&A site. In any case, I'll ask it as a separate question. Thanks

Comment: Also state the goal, i.e. why is it relevant where Jars are downloaded (typically it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

I used Peter's suggestion to run `gradle idea` and imported the project into IntelliJ and I was able to start using the auto-suggestion features in IntelliJ.

Thanks