# Where are the dependency libraries defined in the build.gradle file downloaded?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'd like to know where dependency jars are downloaded. Originally, I wanted to know this since I was trying to understand how I could add these jars specifically to my project class-path in my IntelliJ project but found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986526/using-autosuggest-on-dependency-jars-that-are-downloaded-by-gradle/27003950#27003950). But I'd just like to know what gets downloaded to what location on my machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle's dependency cache is located under `~/.gradle/caches`. (Inspecting the dependencies of the generated IntelliJ project will reveal that.) The exact cache layout is unspecified, and may change between Gradle versions.